# css image max-width inconsistency in google chrome

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with resizing some images inside table cells.

please view this page in chrome and then in IE9/FF:

http://jsbin.com/iqehip/1

yes I know this table gallery markup is beyond horrendous, gladly it isn't mine, the bad part is that I can't change it because it is loaded from a server using a special tag( ie:{{gallery}} )

but that's not the issue I am having currently. as you can see if you view the code at the top in IE/FF the thumbnail images does not downsize the way they do in chrome.

if I give the `table td img` a `width:100%;` it will look fine while there are many thumbnails but when there is only 1 or 2 thumbnails the images will become larger then their original size and be pixelated.

is there any css "hack" or trick that will duplicate the way chrome renders the images with `max-width:100%;` in IE/FF?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the inner `<table>` you want to add

```
table-layout: fixed;
```